# How to cache output HTML in perl script?

Tags: perl, caching, http-caching

Any Perl class available for `Cache` output html ?
database doesn’t need to execute big SQL queries on every page visit

i found many php class and function for `Cache` but in Perl don't have much with example

i am looking this type `Cache` in Perl

```
http://codecanyon.net/item/autocache/1734137
```

please provide detail how can i do in Perl

Thank You

Comment: generating a md5 of the url, using [Digest::MD5](http://perldoc.perl.org/Digest/MD5.html). Safe the page in a directory with the md5 as filename and check your directory for that md5 before entering the normal code. Thats a pretty simple way of caching.

Comment: @Paulchenkiller if possible can you please give example i am student not much expert in perl

Answer (score 0):

Here is the short example. Its important that you need to implement few checks of the requested url. For example, that the url is complete in lowercase, that the protocoll is in front of the url and stuff like that. Everything, that could kill your md5. This is just a reallllllyyy simple caching method. but it should work :)

*not tested*

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Digest::MD5 qw(md5_hex);
use File::Slurp;

my $html = q{};
my $directory_to_md5 = 'directoy/to/md5sums/';
# this md5 comes from the requested url e.g.:
# its important, that the requested url is raw. you need to specify how it looks. for example, that the protocoll is always there.
# just implement a few checks
my $url_md5 = md5_hex('http://my-domain.com/test/call/etc');
# $url_md5 = 31330e57928d52c381e83355ea9e2aa5

if (-f $directory_to_md5 . $url_md5 ) {
  # read_file comes from File::Slurp
  # take a look further look at
  # http://p3rl.org/File::Slurp
  $html = read_file($directory_to_md5 . $url_md5);  
} else {
  # the real code goes here
  # ...
  $html = q{..}; # do stuff here.

  # write_file comes from File::Slurp as well
  write_file($directory_to_md5 . $url_md5, $html);
}
```

EDIT:

I forgot to say, that you need to write your md5-cache-file in the else block